# Javascript code - code check

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and trying to learn some basics.

Can you please check if I had done the following correctly? If not, please outline what I've yet to do.

I had to:

- Calculate the user's month of birth as a number where January=0 through to December=11.
- Take the string entered
- Get the substring being the first three characters
- Convert to uppercase
- Find the starting location of the three letter abbreviation in the month abbreviations string
- Divide this by 3
- (This is not the only way to find the month number, but it allows us to practice searching in a string)

My code:

```
var year = prompt('Enter year of birth as a 4 digit integer');  

var month = prompt('Enter the name of the month of birth');
// Chop everything after the first 3 characters and make it lowercase
month = month.substr(0,3).toLowerCase();
// Store your array in months, differently named than the month input
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct",
"nov", "dec"];  

// We then use array.indexOf() to locate it in the array
var pos = months.indexOf(month);
if (pos >= 0) {
// valid month, number is pos
}
```

Comment: I would personally use substring(0,3) instead of substr and you were asked to do upper, not lowercase - no big difference but if homework...

Comment: The instructions ask to convert to uppercase but you do `toLowerCase`.

Comment: Is there any real question here? Did you test it? Does it work? If not, what doesn't work?

Comment: what is the question actually?

Comment: If the code is working for you and you just want it reviewed for possible enhancements then http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better site for you. StackOverflow is for code that is broken.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren: Just flag for moderator attention to move...

Comment: Sorry guys :( I'm new to the site also. I'll remember to use the proper site next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code obviously does not follow the given instructions:

- Convert to uppercase
- Find the starting location of the three letter abbreviation in the month abbreviations string
- Divide this by 3
- ...to practice searching in a string

But does meet the requirement to *calculate the user's month of birth as a number*. I think array search is even superior to string search (no harm by finding strings between the month names (`"anf"` etc), and also faster because of not checking these possibilities), but they seem to want you to do it with their way.

Answer (score 0):

since you just wanted to know whether your code correct or not, but i thought you write it properly, if you still want to use best practices of javascript, you can refer to following link and you will find so many links on google.

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/24-javascript-best-practices-for-beginners/

by the way, one line code for you functionality can also be written as :

```
if(months.indexOf(month.substr(0,3))>=0) alert("present")
```

Answer (score 0):

The "month abbreviations string" should be `"JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC"`.